# Custom chapter heading with PDFLaTeX using Overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, titlesec

**Description:**

Hello,

I am currently in the process of writing a template for my Bachelor thesis and I'm stuck at an issue I don't know how to resolve. I would like to have these pretty stripes at the beginning of each chapter and I'd like them to go from where the chapter title ends to the top of the page (I combine it with modified `\epigraph` too). When the chapter title spans only one line, there is no issue but when the chapter title is more than one line (2,3,etc.) I am not able to force `\tikzmark` with `\titlesec` (explicit option) to start on the last line.

Provided below is my MWE. Please, excuse the tikz mess, this is early stages and the code will get cleaned up later. I also provide images of what is correcr and what is not.

**MWE:**

```
\usepackage[newlinetospace,newparttoc,toctitles,explicit]{titlesec} % titlesec load
\usepackage{microtype} % \textls command

% PART FORMATTING %
    \titleformat{\part}[display]
        {\sffamily\color{ctublue}}%
        {\filleft\vspace{.5\textheight-8cm}\textls{PART}~\thepart}
        {0pt}
        {\filleft\huge\bfseries#1}%
        []

    \titleformat{name=\part,numberless}[display]
        {\sffamily\filleft\color{ctublue}}%
        {\vspace{.5\textheight-8cm}}
        {0pt}
        {\huge\bfseries#1}%
        []

% CHAPTER FORMATTING %
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
        {\sffamily\color{ctublue}}
        {\textls{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}}~\thechapter}
        {0pt}%
        {\raggedright\color{ctublue}\bfseries\huge#1\tikzmark{CH1}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- (current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=11/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=11/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=22/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=22/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=33/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=33/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=44/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=44/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=55/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=55/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=66/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=66/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=77/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=77/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=88/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=88/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=99/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=99/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=110/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=110/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=121/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=121/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=132/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=132/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=143/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=143/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=154/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=154/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=165/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=165/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=176/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=176/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=187/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=187/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=198/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=198/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=209/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=209/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=220/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=220/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=231/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=231/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=242/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=242/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=253/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=253/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=264/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=264/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=275/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=275/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=286/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=286/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=297/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=297/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=308/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=308/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=319/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=319/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=330/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=330/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=341/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=341/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=352/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH1}) -- ([yshift=352/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH1});
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        []%

    \titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
        {\sffamily\raggedright\color{ctublue}}
        {}
        {0pt}
        {\huge\bfseries#1\tikzmark{CH2}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- (current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=11/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=11/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=22/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=22/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=33/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=33/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=44/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=44/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=55/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=55/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=66/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=66/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=77/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=77/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=88/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=88/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=99/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=99/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=110/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=110/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=121/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=121/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=132/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=132/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=143/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=143/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=154/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=154/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=165/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=165/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=176/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=176/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=187/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=187/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=198/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=198/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=209/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=209/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=220/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=220/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=231/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=231/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=242/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=242/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=253/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=253/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=264/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=264/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=275/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=275/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=286/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=286/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=297/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=297/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=308/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=308/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=319/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=319/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=330/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=330/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=341/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=341/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
            \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=\textwidth+4cm,yshift=352/2pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:CH2}) -- ([yshift=352/2pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:CH2});
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        []

% SECTION FORMATTING %
    \titleformat{\section}[hang]
        {\sffamily\Large\color{ctublue}\filright}
        {}
        {0pt}
        {\color{ctublue}\bfseries\thesection\hspace{1pc}#1}
        [\vskip-5.5pt]

    \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[hang]
        {\sffamily\Large\color{ctublue}\filright}
        {}
        {0pt}
        {\color{ctublue}\bfseries#1}
        [\vskip-5.5pt]

% SUBSECTION FORMATTING %
    \titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
        {\sffamily\large\color{ctublue}\filright}
        {}
        {0pt}
        {\bfseries\color{ctublue}\thesubsection\quad#1}
        []
    
    \titleformat{name=\subsection,numberless}[hang]
        {\sffamily\large\color{ctublue}\filright}
        {}
        {0pt}
        {\bfseries#1}
        []

% SUBSUBSECTION FORMATTING %
    \titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]
        {\sffamily\large\color{ctublue}\filright}
        {}
        {0pt}
        {\bfseries#1}
        []

% PRETTY EPIGRAPH %
\newcommand{\epih}[4]{
\epigraphhead[#1]{\epigraph{\itshape#2}{\tikzmark{#4}#3}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
    \draw[ctulightblue!50,line width=2pt] ([xshift=12.5cm,yshift=16pt]current page.west |- {pic cs:#4}) -- ([yshift=16pt]current page.east |- {pic cs:#4});
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

**The colors are defined as:**

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{ctublue}{RGB}{4,100,188}
    \definecolor{ctulightblue}{cmyk}{.3,.13,0,0}
    \colorlet{ctulightbluebg}{ctulightblue!15!white}
```

**Images:**
*Correct behavior*
[image]

*Incorrect behavior*
[image]

Comment: Hi!  You must provide a full MWE, at least one that returns the two cases appearing in the graphical example.  Your code must start with `\begin{document}` and so on.

Comment: Well, I have a very minimal `main` file since I use the `\input` a lot (for `\input{preamble}` etc.) and titlesec is loaded into this preamble by `\input{titlesec.tex}` hence why I'm providing the titlesec source code only.